# Visual-Assist Add Include directive

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-assist

I have a project name "HelloWorld"

```
Folder "include"
Class1.h
Class2.h

Folder "src"
Class1.cpp
```

If I use the the feature "Add #include Directive" from `Class1.cpp`, the following include gets added:

```
#include "..\include\Class2.h"
```

But in my project I don't use relative paths, so I would like to get something like this:

```
#include <MyProject\include\Class2.h>
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You have to put the *parent* directory of `MyProject` in the include search path.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Which include search path are you taking about exactly? because I've tried both the visual studio c++ directories, and manually setting visual assist directories to custom, and (adding the path) and it works only when I set it, when I restart visual studio - visual assist realizes the directory where the project is located and the included search path are the same, and removes it from my custom list. I've tried adding it to both "Stable include files" & "Other include files" and nothin. The one from stable is removed on restart, and the one from "other" is not, but is ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have what you want happening, with Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Assist build 2094.

In the Project properties (right click on the project, not the solution, in solution explorer) and set:

C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories = the path to the directory holding MyProject\

then exit Visual Studio and set the registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Whole Tomato\Visual Assist X\VANet14\AddIncludePreferShortestRelativePath = 0

as described here:

https://wholetomato.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W336

then finally, since in your example you have the #include line using <>, I set:

VA Options -> Code Generation -> Add Include style: <>

Comment: Thank you very much sir! This is exactly what I was looking for.